# UP DOWN Focus Handling between TextView and VerticalGridView

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I have a xml file which contains `TextView` and Leanback `VerticalGridView`. Left/right/down focus is working fine, but then I can't refocus `TextView` from `VerticalGridItem`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/live_category_header_height">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium_500"
            android:text="@string/str_dashboard_live_tv"
            android:textColor="@color/common_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/live_category_header_text_size"
            android:focusable="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.multiiptv.m3u.xstream.views.LiveVerticalGridView
        android:id="@+id/live_category_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/live_category_lr_margin"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/live_category_header_grid_margin_tb"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/live_category_header_grid_margin_tb"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/live_category_lr_margin" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following statements to the TextView element:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
app:focusOutEnd="true"
app:focusOutFront="true"
```

If that does not work, please post your presenter code.